# How to call an abstract method (overridden in subclasses) from the superclass?

Tags: java, sorting, methods, polymorphism, superclass

I have an abstract method in an abstract class, Student. 
The Subclass, JUPASStudent overrides it. 
Now I am trying to sort the ArrayList of type Student. It requires to call that abstract method but I am unable to do so.

I am writing here my partial code.

Superclass:

```
abstract class Student {
    protected String name;

    public Student (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    abstract double getResult(); //abstract method 

}
```

Subclass:

```
public class JUPASStudent extends Student {
    private double dseResult;

    public JUPASStudent(String n, double d) {
        super (n);
        this.dseResult = d;
    }

    public double getResult() {
        return dseResult;   //abstract method is overridden here
    }
    public String getName() {
        return super.name;
    }
    public void setResult(double dseResult) { 
        this.dseResult = dseResult;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        super.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now I am writing a Sort function to make an ArrayList (Student class)

```
public ArrayList <Student> sort(ArrayList<Student> sList){
        sList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getResult));
        return sList;
    }
```

Input:

```
A 9
B 5
C 8
```

Expected Output:

```
B 5
C 8
A 9
```

Error

```
-The method comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments (Student::getResult) 

-The type Student does not define getResult(T) that is applicable here
```

Comment: Can you mention what you want to achieve?

Comment: No need to override `getName() / setName()`

Comment: *"but I am unable to do so"* ... why? What is happening?

Comment: I am trying to sort sort students in ArrayList<Student> array list in ascending order of their admission results @K.D.

Comment: @Tom I have edited the question and mentioned the errors in the end

Comment: Maybe you should use `comparingDouble`, not `comparingInt`.

Comment: Yeah, it did work but why comparingDouble?

Comment: Because your result variable is of Double, so you can not compare it with Integer Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have override the method in the subclass, it'll use the implementation of the subclass, so don't worry about calling it explicit, at least in your case

Comment: Error 1: The method comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>) in the type Comparator is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Student::getResult)

Comment: Error 2: The type Student does not define getResult(T) that is applicable here

Comment: try "comparingDouble", cause tour result is a Double, not an Integer

Comment: yeah it removed the error. But I didn't understand: what is 'tour' result?

Comment: @djm probably meant 'your' result

Answer (score 0):

getResult() is returning double, try returning Int and i think it would work.
edit:
or use comparingDouble() method